# Irregular voltage read on 240VAC 1ph Residential

Tags: wiring, 240v

I was called to troubleshoot 1 of 2 minisplit AC units. While testing the voltage on the problem AC, W/ unit off, I got L1-GND=210.6 / L2-GND=9.4 / L1-L2=228

If that wasn't confusing enough, I got completely diferent readings on unit 2.
L1-GND=162.4 / L2-GND=64.1 / L1-L2= 226

At the meter I get nominal 114 on each leg.

So, between meter & AC units, I discover a whole home surge protection system AND a solar array. The solar is SUPOSED to feed directly to power company thru meter creating "credits" toward Bill. I don't know if it's suposed to be isolated from house circuit or not but I found it tied in w/ the house @ a sub panel near meter. (spliced w/ E-tape)
I'm sure the surge units or solar are probably the issue but I don't want to call the power company in case the owner becomes liable and the solar company can't arrive for a week. Meanwhile, I'm absolutely positive the voltage irregularities are killing the sensitive electronics in the AC units.
My question is...
Might there be another explication for these irregularities?

Comment: Sounds like a lost neutral, but if it's good at the meter, it's a lost (disconnected) neutral on the house side, **not** the power company side. So the overall voltage between the 2 hots stays roughly where it should, but without the neutral working the voltage to ground varies with how much is being drawn on each side of the line. Can also be a lost hot, where 240V loads are energizing the other hot line (with some losses) but sounds more like a lost neutral to me.

Comment: Normally, if there is L1 and L2, it is not a "1ph" circuit. Or are L1/L2 designations only at the units' connections?

Comment: Incorrect, @xeeka perfectly normal for the 240V center-tapped single-phase power that most USA/Canada homes are supplied with. Either hot to neutral is 120V nominal, both hots to each other are 240V nominal, and referring to them as L1, L2 is normal. Without an L3 there isn't 3 phase going on. Some folks get confused and think it must be 2-phase, but it's not.

Comment: It is very easy to get (and remain, trust me) confused by this.  It's only "one phase" from the perspective of the supplier, who is delivering one of their three phases to you.  From the perspective of the homeowner, there are *in fact* two phases, regardless of what the supplier calls them.   Professional electricians who work in both commercial and residential tend to (rightly) adopt the power company's nomenclature. Homeowners who never work in or even see a commercial installation and never worked as a linesman find it hard to understand why their two phases are called single phase.

Comment: Come on @jay613 it is 1 phase that is center tapped only 1 phase, guess I should start at the top and work down + Ecnerwal  to troubleshoot for an open neutral turn all 240 (double breaker loads) off this prevents  a single leg from powering the other leg, it looks real even with a low impedance meter most of the time. At least that can start the trouble shooting.

Comment: Are you sure the grounding wire for the circuit in question is properly connected?  Try measuring the voltage for each leg at the breaker(s) for the circuit(s) in question

Comment: jay613 has the exact explanation: A frequency drive for motors which is fed by a single phase voltage produces a 3-phase voltage supply. 
Just like a tapped (to neutral) transformer produces a 2-phase voltage supply out of a single phase voltage.

Answer (score -1):

In order to draw any conclusions, another measurement with  low input impedance is helpful.

Most likely a switched or broken neutral/ground is involved here, but:

To test AC- circuits - especially that are switched off - an electric load should be connected parallel to the multimeter - i.e. to the 2 wires/points that are to be tested. That load must be specified for 240V and should be linear (no LEDs, no electronic switch mode power supply).

F.e., an incandescent lamp, hair dryer or a soldering iron should be fine.

Professional multimeters have a switch to lower the input resistance.

This is important to eliminate those confusing voltages, which are caused by the small capacitances between wires, i.e. across the cable and wire insulation.

Here is a similar problem of confusing voltages:
[Why is there voltage between the hot and traveler or other wires when all switches and fixtures are disconnected?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/246669/why-is-there-voltage-between-the-hot-and-traveler-or-other-wires-when-all-switch)

Comment: I am just curious what meters have a switch to low impedance? I have a dozen ant my only low impeadance meter is a Wiggy and it actually puts a small motor load on the circuit, and it is inductance that causes the “phantom voltages” on an ac circuit

Comment: @EdBeal F.e., this Duspol, which is a standard tool for electricians in Europe:https://www.amazon.de/Spannungs-Durchgangspr%C3%BCfer-Benning-Tasche-Schutzbeutel-Spannungspr%C3%BCfer/dp/B08JDJ28H8

Comment: That might be a thing there but the companies I worked with in the UK all used Fluke, it is cat 4 listed for 600v and that is the minimum so I guess it could be a thing but it’s not “what professionals use”.

Comment: @EdBeal See the Fluke 110 Plus carried by Lowes. It has all the usual front dial selections plus a "LoZ" setting that puts a resistor across the input. I recently recommended it for a SE.DIY poster who was trying to diagnose issues on a 500 foot run of direct buried 4/0 wires (not cable) and was getting results with a normal DVM that didn't make sense to him. His electrical world-view did not allow for capacitance and inductance to have real effects on voltage readings, but once he started measuring on the LoZ setting, all became clear.

Comment: You again go to capacitance on an AC circuit , in the ground all I can say ROTFLMAO , show me Just 1 industrial voltage transformation source . Well you cannot as they are all transformers, that means inductance , but some small bricks on the wall can change voltage with high speed electronics and capacitors but these supply DC  any heavy Xc or Xl load crash those supply’s yes they do make larger switching supplies but a simple inductor will crash even the most expensive switching supply, sorry actual experience proves you read some engineering stuff, but don’t forget yes I have that degree 2

Comment: @mta, the fluke 110 is not really a professional tool, about the lowest grade fluke that could be considered pro for an electrician is the T5600 or the T51000, most techs use 87mk5 or equivalent in reality I have never seen a pro use low Z other than a wiggy and fluke makes one of these also a wiggy vibrates and  fluke calls it a pro and yes you can get a calibration certificate for about a Benjamin more but as a pro tool maybe 30 years ago. But I still see electricians using wiggies today but more often a T5600 , we need volts, amps and continuity no amps on 110. Technicians need accuracy.

Comment: @EdBeal Absolutely, I'm 100% in agreement. I was just answering your original comment, ***"I am just curious what meters have a switch to low impedance?"*** with a comment, ***"See the Fluke 110 Plus"*** so you could see one. Agree this model is not designed for a professional, but for a DIYer with a vague understanding of electricity, it serves a useful purpose by eliminating phantom AC voltage readings. If I see one more post like "Why is my outlet at 70 volts with the switch off?" I think I'll scream.

Comment: @MTA , I know of them , the problem with low Z is the low impeadance loads the circuit and creates false readings also, not so much in home electrical, the phantom voltage is created by the ac sign wave inducing a voltage as the wave goes from zero to a peak back to zero the lines of flux cross the other conductors and induce a voltage (not capacitance but through inductance) I have the same issue with those that say capacitive coupling creates the phantom voltage as you do with the outlet at 70v. Also when some make statements about pros, and they are not one, but an internet only electrician

Comment: Of course, phantom voltages in circuits with open/switched off/floating cables in households like in this case are  caused by capacitances.
The inductivity between household cables are far too low in order to induce substantial voltages @60Hz.
F.e., see
https://www.nema.org/docs/default-source/technical-document-library/phantom-voltages_rev_aug_2020.pdf